# Extract first 3 digits from a Pandas column

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe df:

```
       codeID
0       4829
1       2348
2        401
3        281
4      Z3995 
5       O888
6      v71.9
7        NaN
8     Z863 3
9          9
10        50
```

I wanted to only extract the first 3 digits of the column codeID. If there is any alphabet in front, then I would like to ignore the alphabet. I also wanted to ignore numbers after the decimal. If there is any space between the digits, I wanted to ignore the digits after the space. What i want is the following:

```
       codeID
0        482
1        234
2        401
3        281
4        399 
5        888
6        071
7        NaN
8        863
9        009
10       050
```

I tried to first separate alphabets and numbers using

```
df[['Let', 'Num']] = df['codeID'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)([\d\.]+)', expand=True)
```

but it results in NaN for the rows where there is no alphabet. Could someone suggest me how can i efficiently do this?

Comment: regex `+` matches 1 or more, `*` matches 0 or more. So `[A-Za-z]+` is where it fails

Comment: what it should return if values is `K12L34`?  `12` or `123`?

Comment: @Akshay : in case of K12L34, I would like to return only 12 (012).

Comment: @jf328: I tried with 'df['codeID'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]*)([\d\.]*)', expand=True)' but same results. NaN where alphabet is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) directly as it only extracts the first occurrence, just add [zfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) at the end to fill for the missing digits:

```
result = df.codeID.str.extract(r'(\d{1,3})').squeeze().str.zfill(3)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0     482
1     234
2     401
3     281
4     399
5     888
6     071
7     NaN
8     863
9     009
10    050
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Note that the pattern above searches for the occurrence of at least 1 digit, as in the case of `9` in your input example, up to 3 digits.

Comment: Thank you for providing me a solution. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this can using **lambda and regex**:

```
%%time
df = pd.DataFrame({'CodeID': ['4829','2348','401','281','Z3995', 'O888','v71.9','NaN', 'Z863 3', '9','50']})
print(df['CodeID'].apply(lambda x: 'NaN' if x=='NaN' else re.findall('[0-9]{1,3}', x)[0]).str.zfill(3))
```

Output:

```
0     482
1     234
2     401
3     281
4     399
5     888
6     071
7     NaN
8     863
9     009
10    050
Name: CodeID, dtype: object
Wall time: 0 ns
```

---

**If there are only alphabets in the word then to avoid any error following code can be used:**
1) To print `'NaN'` instead of alphabets:

```
 print(df['CodeID'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('[0-9]{1,3}', x)[0] if re.findall('[0-9]{1,3}', x) else 0).str.zfill(3))
```

Output:

```
0     482
1     234
2     401
3     281
4     399
5     888
6     071
7     NaN
8     863
9     009
10    050
11    NaN
```

2) To print `'000'` instead of alphabets:

```
print(df['CodeID'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('[0-9]{1,3}', x)[0] if re.findall('[0-9]{1,3}', x) else '0').str.zfill(3))
```

Output:

```
0     482
1     234
2     401
3     281
4     399
5     888
6     071
7     000
8     863
9     009
10    050
11    000
```

Hope this will solve the question!

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. Works great for the provided example. But when i run it on the actual dataset, i get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range. Any clue?

Comment: Is there any other value except NaN and strings?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: I think this is when you have all alphabets. What output is required when there is all alphabets? NaN or 000

Answer (score 0):

I did it without a regex, bulkier but still not too bad:

```
df.loc[~df.codeID.isna(), 'codeID'] = df.codeID.dropna().apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
df.loc[~df.codeID.isna(), 'codeID'] = df.codeID.dropna().apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
df.codeID = df.codeID.str.lstrip('acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
df.codeID = df.codeID.str.slice(0,3)
df.codeID = df.codeID.str.zfill(3)

df
>
    codeID
0   482
1   234
2   401
3   281
4   399
5   888
6   071
7   nan
8   863
9   009
10  050
```